# can not post picture on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can able to post text on facebook successfully but when i post message with picture on facebook i am not able to post picture on facebook also i am not getting any kind of error but just getting

```
       json.isNull("id") =  null
```

i have used permission like

```
       private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" };
```

and my code is

```
      try {
            // String response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
            // JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Diegodeals";
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", txtTitle.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtDesc.getText().toString());
            File file = new File(path, "diegodeals.jpg");
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Bitmap bitmap = getResizedBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()), 120, 120);
            byte[] data = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            if (data != null) {
                parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
            }
            parameters.putString("access_token", authenticatedFacebook.getAccessToken());
            authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
            String response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = Util.parseJson(response);
                if (!json.isNull("id")) {
                    isWallPostSuccess = false;
                    return "failed";
                } else {
                    isWallPostSuccess = true;
                    return "success";
                }
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                isWallPostSuccess = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            isWallPostSuccess = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Although if i post text with picture the only text will be posted successfully but not picture...

Answer (score 0):

The `picture` parameter takes in a URL to the picture, not the picture binary itself. Put the picture on some publicly accessible server and link it there, or use Facebook's graph API `/photos` picture upload mechanism.

Comment: Hello Laalto if i use 92x92 dimension size image than it will successfully posted image with this picture parameter

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to upload a photo on Facebook to your own wall is by having a bundle with the parameters "photo" and "caption" to "me/photos".  Note that yours is "picture" and "message" to "me/feed", which doesn't work.

In your example, it looks like you have a local image you want to upload.  This is how to do it:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray(
        "photo",
        Util.getByteArrayFromDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.picture)));
params.putString("caption", "test message here");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener());
```

Otherwise, provide an URL (and not a byte array) for the "picture" parameter, and a string for the "caption" parameter, and post to "me/feed".

Comment: but Jesse Chen i want to post photo to facebook not to upload photo that's why i have used me/feed, i have tested this example if i have used small image than at that time image and caption will be successfully posted but sometime it will not